# Why is this MySQL INSERT INTO running twice?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to use the mysql insert statement below to add information to a database table.  When I execute the script, however, the insert statement is run twice.

Here's the URL mysite.com/save.php?Body=p220,c180

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
//tipping fees application
require('base.inc.php');
require('functions.inc.php');

// connect to the database & save this message there

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);


//$number = formatPhone($_REQUEST['From']);
//if($number != 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'){die('SMS from unknown number');} // kill this if from anyone but mike

$message = $_REQUEST['Body'];
//$Sid = $_REQUEST['SmsSid'];
$now = time();
echo $message;

$message = explode(",",$message);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($message);
echo 'message count = '.count($message);
echo '</pre>';

$i = 0;
$j = count($message);

while($i<$j){
    $quantity =$message[$i];
    $material = substr($quantity, 0, 1);
    $amount = substr($quantity, 1);

    switch ($material) {
        case 'p':
            $m = "paper";
            break;
        case 'c':
            $m = "containers";
            break;
        default:
            $m = "other";
        }

        $count = $dbh->exec("INSERT INTO tippingtotals(sid,time,material,weight) VALUES('$i+$j','$now','$m','$amount')");
        echo $count;
        echo '<br />';

    $i++;
    }



//close the database connection 
    $dbh = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Like most of you, I thought it was because I was starting $i=0 so I added the $i+$j in the insert statement so I could see how items were being inserted into the table. Here's what running the script returns:

[image: script output]

I'm certain there's an error in my logic. I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

I ran LiveHTTPHeaders as suggested below and this is what turned up...

```
http://localhost/mysite/save.php?Body=p180,c220

GET /mysite/save.php?Body=p180,c220 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 19 Apr 2010 22:17:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.63 (Unix) PHP/5.2.11 DAV/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Content-Length: 93
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Turns out that the error is only happening when I load save.php in Chrome.

Comment: What's the value of `$j` right before the loop begins?

Comment: it's set to count of $message right before the loop. it's right there ;)

Comment: It looks save.php is being called twice. What does the code that calls this page look like?

Comment: I'm calling the page directly for testing.

Comment: If you look at the order of your data, the loop is being executed twice.

Answer (score 4):

Without a doubt your condition

```
while($i<$j){
```

is getting evalueated such that it executes twice.

That is - it gets evaluated as

```
 while(0<2)
```

Isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Your `$j` variable, the result of `count($message)` is going to be 2, as `explode(',',"p220,c180")` will give you a two-element array.

Since you're starting with `$i = 0`, and incrementing it by one on each loop, your loop will execute twice before `$i < $j` is no longer a true statement.

Comment: I thought the same thing, that's why I put the $i+$j in the insert statement so I could see how items were being inserted into the table.  Here's what running the script returns.
http://cl.ly/63I

I'm certain there's an error in my logic. I just can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: That's exactly the output I would expect from your code as it currently stands.  On the first loop, `$i` will be 0 and `$j` will be 2, and on the second loop, `$i` will be 1 and `$j` will still be 2.  It's unclear what you are expecting to happen though... if you only want to run the INSERT once, why is it inside a loop?

Comment: I need to increment to the second item in the message array.  It's obvious I'm having a mental block.  If you don't want to keep trying to push this through my dense head, feel free to abandon ship!

Here's what I'm expecting...

http://cl.ly/9oW

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at.  Judging by the output comparison though, it's not just the `INSERT` that's being run twice though, it's the whole script.  Your first output link shows that `$i` gets reset to zero.  Are you sure the whole thing isn't being run twice?

Comment: That's what I thought!  I can't figure out why it would be running twice.  I've removed all non-essential includes, reset mysql and apache with no luck.

Comment: Maybe check that there are no redirects occurring?  Try the Firefox extension LiveHTTPHeaders and capture the output when you request that page.  I definitely think it's a problem with the script being run twice because of that reset of `$i` to `0`.

Comment: Ran the page in Firefox and it works like a charm.  The error is only happening in Chrome.  Strange.

Comment: Good old Chrome, saddling us hard-working web developers with another browser to support.  ;)  Glad you found it... sorry that it's a browser specific issue!  You'll have to spend some quality time debugging the request flow with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

`$i` is `0` and `$j` is initialized with number of elements in the array `$message`. This array is created by using `explode(',', $var)` on a string. This string, contained in `$_GET['Body']`, is `p220,c180`. So the array has two elements, thus `$j = 2`.

The `while` loop will get executed twice before `$i >= $j` (`$i >= 2`).